# Error when trying to upload file to firebase storage

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

E/StorageException: StorageException has occurred.
    User does not have permission to access this object.
     Code: -13021 HttpResult: 403
    The server has terminated the upload session
    java.io.IOException: The server has terminated the upload session
        at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.serverStateValid(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:331)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.shouldContinue(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:300)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:221)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask.lambda$getRunnable$7(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:1072)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask$$Lambda$12.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
     Caused by: java.io.IOException: {  "error": {    "code": 403,    "message": "Permission denied. Could not perform this operation"  }}
        at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.parseResponse(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:433)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.parseErrorResponse(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:450)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.processResponseStream(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:441)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.performRequest(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:272)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.performRequest(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:286)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.internal.ExponentialBackoffSender.sendWithExponentialBackoff(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:70)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.internal.ExponentialBackoffSender.sendWithExponentialBackoff(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:62)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.sendWithRetry(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:467)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.beginResumableUpload(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:268)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:216)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask.lambda$getRunnable$7(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:1072) 
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask$$Lambda$12.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
    StorageException has occurred.

Comment: Can you share your code?

Answer (score 2):

**Add this firebase setting to storage**

And make sure that the user is **signed in before uploading** any files to firebase storage

```
service firebase.storage {
    match /b/{bucket}/o {
      match /{allPaths=**} {
          allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You got:

> E/StorageException: StorageException has occurred. User does not have permission to access this object.

That is because the user you're logging with into Firebase doesn't have permission to access this object of the Firebase storage

So you need to grant the user to have access to this object using [Firebase Storage Security](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security)

For testing, you can allow storage security for all users where you go to [Firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com), navigate to Storage tab on the left pane, and then hit the **Rules** tab, and add the below

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

You can also have a look on the [security samples](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/start#sample-rules) from the docs.